# Java Script: onsubmit="check_rfields();" in form tag of html. But getting failed in validation

Tags: javascript

onsubmit="check_rfields();" in form tag of html. But getting failed in validation.

```js
function check_rfields() { 

    var name = document.getElementById("id_rname").value;

    var email = document.getElementById("id_remail").value;

    var cemail = document.getElementById("id_rcemail").value;

    var password = document.getElementById("id_rpassword").value;

    var cpassword = document.getElementById("id_rcpassword").value;

    if(name=='' || name==0 

        && email=='' ||  email==0 

        && cemail=='' || cemail ==0 

        && password=='' || password==0 

        && cpassword=='' || cpassword==0 ) {

        document.getElementById("onsubmitErr").innerHTML 
                                                    = "All fields arerequired"; 

                return false;   
          }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: One time it shows msg but then go ahead ... means fail...

Comment: You mean you're getting an error? Perhaps you should include the HTML as well.

Comment: "name==0" ? Why this test on a text input ?

Comment: `onsubmit="return check_rfields();"` write like this

Comment: @dystroy : it means when you put a white space in field then it count as a character and then your validation will fail... so to prevent white space you should use "name == 0"

Comment: @mack: oh gr8 it was a really big mistake...thanks all of you... :-)

Comment: @PuzzledBoy Welcome dude, keep coding..

Answer (score 2):

If you want the submit to fail (on failed validation), use:

```
onSubmit="return check_rfields()"
```